# Adding placeholder to django form field and removing default label

Tags: python, django

Please i'm new to django. adding a placeholder to my username and password fields but none is working.
This is the form

```
    class LoginForm(forms.Form):
         username = forms.CharField(label='', help_text='Enter your username',    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Username here'}))
         password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password here'}))
```

Comment: Can you please describe the issue you're seeing in more detail? Also, which version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='', help_text='Enter your username')
    password = forms.CharField(label='')

    class Meta:
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        widgets = {'password': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = _('Enter your username')
```